# Use library from other Zend Project

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have two project in Zend Framework, so I have two librarys different, but I need to use some classes from the other project.

Did you know how can I add those classes into my zend project whithout copy, because when i change one, I must have to change the other??
bouth are in the same server

/www/project1/library/rules/clasess.php

/www/project2/   <-- need the class in this project`

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your include path. In you index.php file use, for example

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
  realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
  realpath('/var/www/project2/library'),
  get_include_path(),
)));
```